# Convert ReadyAPI xpath for use in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml, ready-api

I'm having trouble converting xpath expressions that I use in ReadyAPI for use in Python 3 with the lxml library. I've read the lxml documentation but I'm not getting the same results.

Here's my XML:

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <ReplyResponses>
            <RepyResults>
                <Reply>
                    <ContentsofReply>
                        <Content>
                            <IDofContent>ID of Content 1</IDofContent>
                        </Content>
                    </ContentsofReply>
                    <ID>ID of Reply 1</ID>
                    <Name>Name of Reply</Name>
                </Reply>
            </RepyResults>
        </ReplyResponses>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I use the following xpath expressions in ReadyAPI:

`//*:Reply[*:Name="Name of Reply"]/*:ID`

the expected returned result is:

**ID of Reply 1**

and:

`//*:Reply[*:Name="Name of Reply"]/*:ContentsofReply/*:Content/*:IDofContent`

the expected returned result is:

**ID of Content 1**

How do I get the same results in Python 3 with the lxml library? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath expressions in your questions contain `*:`prefixes intended to be used with namespaces which aren't in your sample xml.

To extract the same data from your sample xml with lxml, change your expressions to

```
//Reply[Name="Name of Reply"]/ContentsofReply/Content/IDofContent/text()
```

to get

```
['ID of Content 1']
```

and to

```
//Reply[Name="Name of Reply"]/ID/text()
```

to get

```
['ID of Reply 1']
```

Comment: thank you, and in the case that I've a XML that does use namespaces, do I need to use the * wildcard in python?

Comment: @FWAF That would depend on the library you use (lxml or elementtree); but depending on the complexity of the xml, you may have to get into declaring namespaces (not fun...)